# django ajax form how to display the result after submission

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am sure it is not a complicated problem, but I have stuck here for a long time, hope some help from you, really appreciated any help.Thanks!!!!

I think it is required to use a "append" function from ajax.But really I am not sure how to write a correct views.py and script. Please see below my snippets and give me your valuable correction.

My current code returns error of "ResultView is missing a QuerySet."

[image]

The picture is self explanatory. User enter information, and then click submit then filter the database based on these information. Finally display the result in the same page.

**models.py**

```
class Input(models.Model):
    company=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region=models.CharField(max_length=100)   

class Result(models.Model):
    sales=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    employee=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Company",error_messages={'required': 'Please enter the company name'},required=True)

    #region(here shows a dropdown list, here is correct)
    iquery = Result.objects.values_list('region', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(region,region)  for region in iquery]
    region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=iquery_choices)
```

**url**

url(r'^result_list/$',ResultView.as_view(),name='dupont'),

**views.py**

```
class ResultView(generic.UpdateView):
    context_object_name = 'dupont_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    form_class = InputForm
    success_url = '/result/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST': # If this view is target on redirect must have GET data.
            form = InputForm(self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                if self.request.is_ajax():
                    company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                    region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                    queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)

                return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype='application/json')
            else:
                print form.errors
        return super(ResultView,self).get_queryset()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
        context["employee"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('employee'))
```

**html**

```
<form id="InputForm" method="post" action="">   #here is the data entry form
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!--enter the company name--> 
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.company.errors }}
            <label id="id_company" name="company" for="{{ form.company.id_for_label }}">Company:</label>
            {{ form.company }}
        </div>

        <!--select region-->
        <div class="field" >
            <label> Select the Region:
            {{ form.region }}
                {% for region in form.region.choices %}
                     <option value="region" name= "region" id="id_region">{{region}} </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </label>
        </div>

        <!--submit-->
        <p><input type="button" value="Submit" /></p></div>
    </form> 
</div>

<script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#InputForm").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    var region= $("#id_region").val();
    var company= $("#id_company").val();

        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            type: $(this).attr('post'),
            url: "dupont_list/",
            success: function(data) { // on success..
                $("#result").html(data); // update the DIV "result"

              ---how to update the html with filtered result---?
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

    <div id="result" class="result">   <!--Showing the filtered result in database-->
    <table>
    <tr><b>Sales</b></tr>
    <td> {{sales.sales__sum}}</td>

    <tr><b>Employee</b></tr>
    <td> {{employee.employee__sum}}</td>
    </table>
```

**traceback**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  267.         self.object = self.get_object()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_object
  32.             queryset = self.get_queryset()
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\SCOR\dupont\views.py" in get_queryset
  46.         return super(ResultView,self).get_queryset()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get_queryset
  74.                         'cls': self.__class__.__name__

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /result_list/
Exception Value: ResultView is missing a QuerySet. Define ResultView.model, ResultView.queryset, or override ResultView.get_queryset().
```

**Updated Views.py based on Anush's suggestion**

```
class ResultView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'result_list'
    template_name = 'result_list.html'
    form_class = InputForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if self.request.is_ajax():
                company = form.cleaned_data['company']
                region = form.cleaned_data['region']

                queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region)
                sales = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
                return
                data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset,sales)  

                HttpResponse(data)
         else:
             return HttpResponse(form.errors)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Result.objects.all()   
       def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views.py -> ResultView you are overriding the get_queryset() function which should return a queryset.

so change your get_queryset like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Result.objects.all()
```

and handle your post separately like:

```
from django.core import serializers

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            region = form.cleaned_data['region']
            queryset=Result.objects.filter(region=region).aggregate(Sum('sales'))
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(queryset))
    else:
         return HttpResponse(form.errors)
```

Your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(this).attr('post'),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "dupont_list/",
    success: function(data) {
        var html = "<table>"
        html += "<td>"+data['sales__sum']+"</td>"
        html += "</table>"
        $("#result").html(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks~~can u please take a look at my html, do I need to use "append" function to display the filtered result?

Comment: i have edited my answer..changed views and added ajax call

Comment: Hi@Anush, thank u a lot~~I updated the views.py as you suggest, but I have 2 questions (also noted in snippets): 1. if return Result.objects.all() returns only the filtered result or the whole database? 2. data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset) , if here only render queryset result to json, or not only queryset result but also calculation result(I mean in context_data, there is aggregate() result)?  Thanks a lot for your clarification.

Comment: 1. yes Result.objects.all() will returns all the objects in the table.
2. Only serialized queryset will be sent in json not the context data

and i had made a small mistake in def post() i have edited my answer.

Comment: Hi@ Anush, thanks. 1. so the flows in views.py is like: from def get_queryset(self), it gets the database data -->from def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs), it gets the form data, and then do the filter thing based on user input, return the queryset result to json --->def get_context_data:display the result. Please correct me if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Hi @Anush. Q2: But in the html, I need to show the aggregate result which is handled in 【def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):context["sales"] = self.get_queryset().aggregate(Sum('sales'))】, but we only send the serialized queryset (filtered by region) to json. So do I need to put the "aggregate" code before 【data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)】？ I put the changed code in 【Updated Views.py based on Anush's suggestion】，can u please take a look~~thanks a lot^_^

Comment: from what i understand, you want to display the aggregate sales after post. so i have edited my answer. you dont need "get_context_data" and change ListView to CreateView because ListView does not have a post method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93139/discussion-between-elena-and-anush).